# What are the differences between GTX 650 and the GTX 650Ti?

Tags: performance, graphics-card, hardware

I can't find a comparison *anywhere*... what are the advantages of the Ti version?

I noticed that the normal 650 has 384 cores, while the 650Ti has 768 cores...

How... Does this not make a ridiculously huge difference?

Also, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. Please tell me if it's not. :c

Comment: Usually searching for "x vs y" (in this case GTX 650 vs GTX 650Ti) will turn up several comparison reviews.  AnandTech and TomsHardware are both good sites to check.

Comment: Except... That's exactly what I searched and it turned up absolutely nothing of the sort.

Comment: Huh, really?  I did this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=GTX+650+vs+GTX+650Ti  and in the top 5 hits is both an AnandTech and TomsHardware article putting them head to head (along with the rest of the line + some AMD cards) in a full set of benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTX 650 Ti is targeted to be between 650 & 660 in terms of power, Tom's hardware has a good [review](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-650-ti-benchmark-gk106,3318.html) with a comparison vis a vis normal 650.

Comment: Thanks! Tom's hardware was the first place I checked, not sure how I missed that...